# php curl get page like human

Tags: php, curl

When I browse online.az site with chrome internet browser everything is OK. Site is opening for me. But I want to open this site with curl. My php code:

```
// cookie //
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, '');
fclose($handle);
// cookie //
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
global $tmpfname;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$get = file_get_contents_curl('https://online.az//');
echo $get;
```

But with this code site is not opening.

Comment: opening https://online.az// in a browser gives `403 forbidden` ... ?

Comment: All I get from it is 403 Forbidden, and that is in real browser. And yes, I'm a human.

Comment: On your country it may. But I can browse this site normally on our country. And I want to open this site with php. I am using WAMP. So I am sure that online.az is not blocked my site

Comment: More likely the site is somehow misconfigured. What is *az* it anyway, Azerbaijan?

Comment: why voting down? what is the reason?

Comment: .az it means Azerbaijan

Comment: site is working for Azerbaijan

Comment: Why would the site be misconfigured? Some sites are just blocked from other countries. For instance you cannot view video's on the BBC website if you're not in the UK, although blocking the entire site with just a 403 is a bit harsh.. And of course it makes answering a question somewhat harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an HTTPS site, so there is SSL to deal with. The quick fix would be to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This just bypasses the certificate verification.

The better fix would be to *enable* verification, but to do that, you would have to download the certificate from the server and save it, so PHP can compare it with the server version.

Then you can add it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "PathToYour/Certificate.crt");
```

For a more elaborate explanation, please see this tutorial:
[*Using cURL in PHP to access HTTPS (SSL/TLS) protected sites*](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)

Comment: Yeah worked! Thanks! I will mark as answer!